# How to make an object move in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started to use Unity and I found on Youtube a tutorial for my question(making an object move with arrow keys), but I have a problem. My object is constantly moving into the right bottom corner(x is going to minus and z is going to +, y is zero). I did the same thing as the guy in the tutorial.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Rigidbody component added to your object?
If you do, uncheck "Use Gravity" and check "Is Kinematic" in the Unity Editor, inspector window.
That might help solve the problem.

Comment: Now my object does not even move.
Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: What components did you add to your object? Maybe something else is interacting with it